# Where did the term "cheesy" come from?

Tags: etymology, colloquialisms

Why do we call frivolous, lame or naff things cheesy?

Comment: I'm wondering why we call "naff" things, well, naff things. ;-)

Comment: [See here](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=naff&searchmode=none), I didn't realise that!

Comment: Interesting that etymonline seems to be the only source for *that* origin.

Comment: The OED lists both these meanings of "naff", but says of each that it is probably unrelated to the other. It doesn't give any reason for this, though.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Interestingly enough, [Etymonline suggests](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=cheesy&searchmode=none) that it has nothing to do with *cheese*:

> "cheap, inferior," 1896, from Urdu *chiz* "a thing," from Persian *chiz*, from O.Pers. **ciš-ciy* "something," from PIE pronomial stem **kwo-* (see *who*). Picked up by British in India by 1818 and used in the sense of "a big thing" (especially in the phrase *the real chiz*). By 1858, *cheesy* had evolved a slang meaning of "showy," which led to the modern, ironic sense.

*Cheese*, on the other hand, ultimately comes from Latin (*caseus*), taking a detour via West Germanic (compare German *Käse*, Dutch *kaas*).

Comment: Aha! Is this also the origin of calling someone a "big cheese"? I wonder if it's related to [Molesworth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nigel_Molesworth)'s "chiz".

Comment: @Tom: Moleworth's *chiz* is from *chizzer* "swindler" which is from *chizz* or *chizzle* which are slang forms of *chisel* "cheat, defraud".

Answer (score 2):

[Another](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=cheesy) etymology dictionary has a different take:

> cheesy (adj.) Meaning "cheap, inferior" is
>   attested from 1896, perhaps originally U.S. student slang, along with
>   cheese (n.) "an ignorant, stupid person." In late 19c. British slang,
>   cheesy was "fine, showy" (1858), probably from cheese (n.2) and some
>   suggest the modern derogatory use is an "ironic reversal" of this. The
>   word was in common use in medical writing in the late 19c. to describe
>   morbid substances found in tubers, decaying flesh, etc.

Upon second look, this etymology also comes from Etymonline.com, the same source as the other answer posted. So it appears that this website has updated their information on this topic since 2011. That is puzzling because they have entirely dropped the stuff about "Urdu chiz", which is just a bit suspicious. Are they just making this stuff up?

Comment: FYI: Urdu 'cheez' is nearly equal to 'thing'. But it can not be used as a work/task e.g. 'I am doing my thing' in English. But is used even to refer someone e.g. 'what is this thing (person)'

Comment: The Etymonline editor didn't make up the part about the meaning of Urdu and Persian *chiz* / چیز (which is LifeH2O's point, I think). About the etymology, I doubt he made it up, but I wish there were references to follow.