# Verb for defeating someone or something in a video game by using cheap tactics

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, terminology

I lost in street fighter by getting low kicked to death.

I tell my opponent

> you _________ed me (to death)

or

I beat a difficult boss in a video game by exploiting a glitch.

> I beat UberBoss by __________ing him.

Comment: I've heard that called "cheesing" ...  here is an example of using the term 'cheese' in a title of a "discussion"  https://www.reddit.com/r/gametales/comments/34tkev/dd_5e_how_to_cheese_a_dungeon_part_1_we_didnt/

Comment: Hadouken Spamming?

Comment: It's amazing to me that some people expect that English will have a readymade word for every aspect of a technology that's been introduced a weekend ago. Those guys that invented English sure did a good job.

Comment: *cheating*? *hitting below the belt*?

Comment: @JohnLawler Yes, it's fascinating how new words are begged for. You're underestimating the magnitude and prevalence of playing computer games in peoples lives though.  It is a huge "hobby" with 10s of millions of people spending 40 plus hours a week (4 or 5 hours afterwork.. plus weekend time),  and some games(not all are competitive in design but some are) have international competitions with prize purses over a million dollar per participant. http://www.polygon.com/2016/8/13/12469018/here-are-the-winners-of-valve-s-20-million-2016-international-dota-2-championships

Comment: They'll be making up their own words and phrases, then. There'll never be an official entry for something that ephemeral.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Origins of the gaming term "cheese strategy"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21867/origins-of-the-gaming-term-cheese-strategy)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a word for annoying behavior which decreases enjoyment for the other players in a game?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/181836/what-is-a-word-for-annoying-behavior-which-decreases-enjoyment-for-the-other-pla)

Answer (score 1):

Though unofficial (and bad?) English perhaps an idea from [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=glitching&amp=true&defid=4255805) would work.   As mentioned in comments a 'official' dictionary may be tricky to find for something so new!

> **glitching**
> The act of exploiting glitches, errors, mistakes, or a bug in a system for harmless fun or devious mischief.
>
> Glitching can also mean that a system, such as a computer, is experiencing many glitches and technical problems at once.
> *He has been at the bank glitching that ATM machine all night...*

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using the words "trick" or "deceive" in an appropriate form. The words are applicable in any context, including video games.

trick:    cunningly deceive or outwit.

Answer (score 0):

A word I might is **[gyp](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/gyp)**

> *Informal: Sometimes Offensive.* To defraud or rob by some sharp practice; swindle; cheat.